# Alert window if there is no keydown for number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if there are no keydowns or clicks for 10 seconds and if so display an alert window, I can use jquery if it's more efficient than simple js.

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the most efficient coding process, or most efficient code at runtime?

Comment: hah sorry, I have no idea what I tried to say. I just googled it, I suppose it would be the most efficient at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(function(){

    var timer;
    function resetTimer(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            alert('No keydown for 10 seconds');   
            // Call reset timer here if you want the timer to start again
            // when the alert is closed

            // Otherwise, if you want to stop the timer forever,
            // remove the event handler from document.onkeydown
        }, 10000);
    }
    resetTimer();

    document.onkeydown = resetTimer;

})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/2RB2g/)

It assumes you haven't bound anything else to the documents keydown listener. If you have then you should use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` instead.

Comment: Is setting/clearing timeout on each keydown efficient performance-wise? I mean, when someone is typing, we are getting lots of timers created/cleared.

Comment: @Li0liQ On my laptop in Chrome the function `resetTimer()` can execute ~ 350,000 times per second. If anyone can type that fast, that's scary :P. The nice thing is that it's also idle when the user is idle instead of taking up (however small) CPU even when the user is idle.

Comment: Seem to remember that the requirements were for **keydowns or clicks** so you might want to add a click listener on the body too.

Answer (score 2):

```
var seconds = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
  seconds++;
  if(seconds == 10) {
    alert("No keydown or click in 10 seconds");
  }
}, 1000);

$('body').live('click keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  seconds = 0;
});
```

Must have jQuery.

Comment: I edited this, you had the setInterval amount set to "1", but timer units are milliseconds, not seconds, so I changed it to "1000".

Comment: Hmm, just out of habit. Depending on the use-case, you can include it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

- Set a variable to track whether a key/click happens, say `var action_happened = false;`
- Set a 10-second timer (10000 millisecond setTimer).
- Inside the timer's callback, if `!action_happened` then display an alert.
- Set up global click/keypress event handlers. Their callbacks will just `action_happened = true;`
- If you really want to go for efficiency, after setting `action_happened = true;`, remove the click/keypress handlers. That's optional though, it's plenty efficient without this step.